# Get how many fields are null or empty string in DJANGO model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I've the next model:

```py
class Iniciativa(models.Model):
    iniciativa      = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    canal           = models.ForeignKey(Canales, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    territorio      = models.JSONField(default=list, blank=True, null=True)
    bigbet          = models.ForeignKey(BigBet, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objetivo        = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    call2action     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    dialogo_valor   = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cobertura       = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    kpi_medicion    = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I made a command to pass the information from a file to the database, there is a field that carries the % of the filling progress, from the front I manage it with an event every time something changes but I don't know how to emulate that behavior from my command I thought if there is a simpler way other than manually checking each field to see the progress?

Comment: Can you show your command ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a property should do the trick for your model:

```
class Iniciativa(models.Model):
    # Fields as defined in your model

    @property
    def progress(self):
        total_fields = len(self._meta.fields)
        non_null_fields = sum(field.value_to_string(self) != '' for field in self._meta.fields if field not in ["id"])
        return round((non_null_fields / total_fields) * 100)
```

You could change `for field in self._meta.fields if field not in ["id"]` to `for field in self._meta.fields if field not in ["id", "other_field"]` if you want other fields excluded as well

In your custom command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.models import Iniciativa

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Import data from file'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Read data from file and create Iniciativa instances

        for iniciativa in Iniciativa.objects.all():
            print(f'Progress for {iniciativa.iniciativa}: {iniciativa.progress}%')
```